# Why can't I buy a magma burger?

Tags: paper-mario-color-splash

I am having trouble buying the magma burger. It tells me it is sold out. I checked in my items list, but it isn't in there. Why can't I buy it?

Comment: I've not played, so take this with a grain of salt, but people keep mentioning it ends up in your Key Items and isn't a Thing card, so have you checked there to make sure you don't already have it?

Comment: Yeah I looked up the problem online and i saw some people overlooked it in their items. But I looked and I do not have it yet

Comment: Well apparently there was a glitch of some sort, I just went to the dragon anyway and it let me use the fishing pole and magma burger even though it said I didn't have them